# How do I determine the player's grid position?

Tags: mathematics, procedural-generation, tilemap, grid, godot

My original method for doing this involved taking the player's position, dividing it by the grid cell size, and rounding the result. This works for most cases except when I move my player up above y-axis zero or to the left of x-axis 0. I use the grids to load chunks of procedurally generated tiles into my scene.

it keeps resulting in -0 being a component of the position vectors, which throws my system off. I fixed that by converting each component to integers, but that doesn't solve the greater problem.

There must be a more effective method for this available.

EDIT:

I am using Godot Engine and GDscript for the game I am creating.

This is my code:

```
    func calculate_grid_position():
    var grid_position = Vector2(int(round(position.x/ 1600)),
                                int(round(position.y/ 1600)))
    return grid_position
```

Comment: This isn't nearly enough information to help you. What engine and programming language are you using? What does your current code look like?

Comment: The code you've shown is what we typically use for this situation. Using this code, an x position between -800 and 800 maps to column 0, -2400 to -800 maps to column -1, and 800 to 2400 maps to column +1. How does this differ from what you need?

Comment: @DMGregory I get my player to walk to the top left and instead of spawing the appropriate chunk it does nothing At grid position (-0,0), it just spawns the chunk at (0,0). I get (-0,0) instead of (-1,0)

Comment: Well, did you try drawing your algo with pen and paper? From the description it looks right, you might have a bug elsewhere.

Comment: @Kromster I'll investigate.

Comment: A super simple solution you can use is to start the player in the middle of the grid and not let them move past 0 on either axis.

Answer (score 1):

It's common for negative zero to behave in unintuitive ways. Complicating things, I wasn't able to find an official doc detailing what sort of behavior a programmer should expect from Godot regarding negative zero.

So the best suggestion I can offer is to special case `-0` to behave as needed:

```
func calculate_grid_position():
    var tempX = int(round(position.x/ 1600)
    if tempX == -0:
        tempX = -1
    var tempY = int(round(position.y/ 1600)
    if tempY == -0:
        tempY = -1
    var grid_position = Vector2(tempX, tempY)
    return grid_position
```

It would be a good idea not to hard coded the cell size (int this case `1600`), but without more knowledge about your code, I can't specifically tell you how to fix that other than suggesting you to move those values into a variable or a constant.

As an end note, the desired mapping as described in the question & comments seems a bit unusual. I generally wouldn't expect `-0` to arise under most situations. When I have needed to handle it as a special case, I've either converted it to `0` or treat it as an error / exception.

Comment: I agree `-0` can act in unintuitive ways but I suspect `-0` should become `0` and not `-1` in this case. Otherwise the grid cell for 0 would include 0 ≤ x < 800 instead of -800 ≤ x < 800.

Comment: @amitp I agree that the mapping *is* unusual. My read was that OP specifically identified the the code given worked except that `-0` needed to map to `-1`. But it probably bears mentioning - I'll add an edit & would gladly update further if OP provides additional info.